# HTTPClient never leaves socketRead() when executing GET on stream - workaround?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient (from Apache HTTP Components 4.3) in order to execute a GET against a ShoutCast stream:

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://relay3.181.fm:8062/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

The call to client.execute() never returns, and according to the debugger it is a nested invocation to java.net.SocketInputStream#socketRead0() which is the last node in the call stack. From profiling the code, my only conclusion (based on a steadily rising number of char[] allocations) is that it simply "latches on" to the stream and keeps pulling bytes from the socket indefinitely.

What I would like is for the client to simply work normally and give me a HTTPResponse which I can use to pull what I want from the stream. As a matter of fact, I have been able to do so with other ShoutCast streams, but not this one.

Is there any way to work around this? Could I for example tell the client to break off after a certain number of bytes?

Comment: If it blocks permanently it isn't reading continuously. The two are mutually exclusive. What's your evidence?

Comment: @EJP - I have changed the wording to make it clearer what was meant.

Comment: If it never returns it is blocked. 'Latches on' is a figment of your imagination. It can only read as many bytes as you told it to read, then it will return.

Comment: Dear @EJP, this is exactly what I said to begin with, and apparently that was not good enough for you. You are welcome to edit my question yourself to fit whatever you are expecting. Also, I would appreciate if you run the code yourself if you are not clear on what I am saying - I said "latch on" because this is what is happening - it does NOT read "as many bytes as I tell it to", it keeps on reading indefinitively, until I manually close the program. This may very well be an issue with HTTPClient, in which case I would appreciate some pointers to work around it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That site is very particular. If you don't specify a supported `User-Agent` (like Mozilla), the server keep streaming bytes. I don't know what these bytes are meant to represent, audio perhaps.

If you print out the bytes that you receive, you will see

```
ICY 200 OK
icy-notice1:<BR>This stream requires <a href="http://www.winamp.com/">Winamp</a><BR>
icy-notice2:SHOUTcast Distributed Network Audio Server/Linux v1.9.8<BR>
icy-name:181.FM - The Beatles Channel
icy-genre:Oldies
icy-url:http://www.181.fm
content-type:audio/mpeg
icy-pub:1
icy-br:128
```

which indicates that the response is not a valid HTTP response. It is an ICY response from the ICY protocol.

Now the default `HttpClient` you are using uses a `DefaultHttpResponseParser` which is a

> Lenient HTTP response parser implementation that can skip malformed
>   data until a valid HTTP response message head is encountered.

In other words, it keeps reading the bytes the server is sending until it finds a valid `HTTP` response header, which will never happen, thus the infinite read.

I don't think you will be able to accomplish what you want with the Http Components library. Either look for an `ICY` client implementation in Java or spin your own.

Comment: I think one can add support for the ICY protocol relatively easily by implementing a custom LineParser (http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.3.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/LineParser.html)

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem as far as my question goes, and it seems (as per the comment by @oleg) that the proper approach to finally solving it is implementing a LineParser supporting ICY. Thanks to you both!